# FragmentTransation setCustomAnimations not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I trying to use the new android compatibility package to include fragments into my project.
I am trying to include a transition animation when I add a new fragment. The thing is only one of my animation work. The In animation works but the Out animation doesn't work.
     I read somewhere that it is a bug in the compatibility package. But I also read that the bug was fixed in the 3rd revision of the compatibility package. Can anyone help me with this issue

In Animation

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/anticipate_interpolator"
android:fromXDelta="0"
android:toXDelta="0"
android:fromYDelta="100%"        
android:toYDelta="0%"
android:duration="1000"/>
```

Out Animation

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:fromXDelta="0"
android:toXDelta="0"
android:zAdjustment="top"
android:fromYDelta="0%"        
android:toYDelta="100%"
android:duration="1000"/>
```

This is the code I use to add fragments

```
newFragment = new HelloWorldFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.bottom_top_animation, R.anim.top_bottom_animation);
ft.add(R.id.outer_layout, newFragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: There is no info about resolving animation problem in 3rd revision: http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html#Notes

Comment: I kinda abandoned fragments for the time being as I didnt feel it was mature enough to implment in a large project.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This works in the current version of the library, but it was definitely broken previously.  You can use something like this:

```
final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down, R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down)
  .add(R.id.fragment_container, new SomeFragment(), FRAGMENT_TAG)
  .addToBackStack(FRAGMENT_TAG)
  .commit();
```

where R.anim.slide_up is your in animation and R.anim.slide_down is your out animation.  The second pair of params (3 and 4) for setCustomAnimations allow you to specify the pop in/out animations for popping the backstack (e.g., when the user presses back, the fragment will animate away with the animation specified as the fourth param).

Comment: it;s responding me Unknown animator name: translate... error...any idea if i am missing anything here?

Comment: The slide_down animation does not seem to be working for me.  Instead the fragment just gets removed and disappears with no slide animation.

Comment: You cannot use setCustomAnimations with get**Support**FragmentManager

Comment: @MAGx2 You can use setCustomAnimations with getSupportFragmentManager().  However, after API 11, you must use ObjectAnimators, typically stored in R.animator, instead of translate animators.

Comment: Note that in the current version of the support library (21.0.2) , you can't use "setCustomAnimations". This is a known issue : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77670 .

Comment: for 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3': animations are working but it is important to call setCustomAnimations before add/replace.

Comment: For me the problem was that i was setting custom animations before adding the fragment. First set animations then add did the trick This post helped. Thanks

Comment: Make sure to call .setCustomAnimations() BEFORE calling .add() or .replace(). This had me banging me head for hours...

Comment: @stefan.nsk thank you for this...save me alot of time

Answer (score 8):

I have found a workaround for this. Override onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) in your fragment class then its working fine.

```
@Override
public Animation onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
    return enter ? AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.grow_fade_in_center) : AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.shrink_fade_out_center);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean 'onCreateAnimator'?

Comment: Method name is same as mentioned in above code snippet Its fragment method just override this.

Comment: exit animation is still not working for me. First fragment is replaced and then its entry animation is being played but exit animation is not being played for previous fragment

Comment: transit and nextAnim parameters always are 0!

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem too, here's my situation:

1. I want to do some UI change after exit animation. but I found that exit animation didn't work. my UI change codes are in onBackPressed().

my solution is as following:

1. move UI change logic in onCreateAnimator(). and then exit animation works.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below example:

```
 private fun gotoFragment(fragment:Fragment){
     parentFragmentManager.commit {
        setCustomAnimations(
             R.anim.slide_in,
           R.anim.fade_out,
              R.anim.fade_in,
             R.anim.slide_out
        )
         setReorderingAllowed(true)
        replace(R.id.fragment_dashboard_container, fragment)
        addToBackStack(null)
    }
}
```

Here is the doc [Fragment transactions](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions)